# GNU make: friendly way to choose mutually exclusive files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm writing a GNU makefile to create a license file like so: if the customer's file exists then copy it to the package directory, else use the generic license. I have about a dozen files that have the same copy pattern. The goal is to copy one of the two mutually exclusive source files onto the target filename.

Is there a better way to express this with GNU make syntax? Here's what I currently have. I considered copying all GENERIC files to the directory, then overwriting with the existing CUST files.

```
$(PDIR)/license.txt: | $(PDIR)
   if [ -f Package/license.txt.$(CUST) ] ; \
   then \
       cat Package/license.txt.$(CUST) >$(PDIR)/license.txt ; \
   else \
       cat Package/license.txt.GENERIC >$(PDIR)/license.txt ; \
   fi
```

**Edit:** Thanks to MadScientist for the help. Here's my final working version:

```
TARGETS = license.txt ...
final: $(addprefix ${PDIR}/,${TARGETS})
    @echo some output

$(foreach T,${TARGETS},$(eval ${PDIR}/$T: $(firstword $(wildcard Package/$T.${CUST} Package/$T.GENERIC Package/$T)) | ${PDIR}))

$(addprefix ${PDIR}/,${TARGETS}):
    @echo Creating substituted version of $< as $@
    @sed --expression="\
            ... \
        < '$<' \
        > '$@'

${PDIR}:
    mkdir $@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcard, then (as always) you should use automatic variables.  Like this:

```
$(PDIR)/license.txt: $(firstword $(wildcard Package/license.txt.$(CUST) Package/license.txt)) | $(PDIR)
        cat '$<' > '$@'
```

If you have a lot of these you can also use a loop to define the targets:

```
TARGETS = license.txt

$(foreach T,$(TARGETS),$(eval $(PDIR)/$T: $(firstword $(wildcard Package/$T.$(CUST) Package.$T) | $(PDIR))))

$(addprefix $(PDIR)/,$(TARGETS)):
        cat '$<' > '$@'
```

Comment: I'm reading the docs to try to understand what's going on. In your second example, the last make target is including only the first file in ${TARGETS}. How do I resolve that? Also the $(PDIR) isn't being created, what the purpose of "|$(PDIR)" in the foreach?

Comment: Nevermind, the foreach was missing a closing paren and I put it in the wrong place. Thank you!